# applying a Method to only one object of a class

Tags: c++, oop

So I am currently developing a simple version of battleship and I have a problem when trying to color the buttons.

Since there are many buttons I am developing them with two for loops that add them to a grid in the UI. Each button is identified by a x coordinate, y coordinate and a player number (either a 1 or a 2).

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);


    /**
    /  UI Button connects
    **/
     connect(ui->closeButton2,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(closeWindow()));



    /**
    / Generates Player 1 Field and sets color to Blue
    **/

    ui->gridLayout1->setVerticalSpacing(0);
    ui->gridLayout1->setHorizontalSpacing(0);



    for(int x = 0 ; x < 10 ; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0 ; y < 10 ; y++)
        {
            Button *button = new Button( x , y,1);                                                            //New Objects
            ui->gridLayout1->addWidget(button, x, y);                                                       //adds buttons to right Widget
            button->setStyleSheet("background-color: blue");                                                //sets all buttons to color blue
            connect(button,SIGNAL(mySignal(int,int,int)),this,SLOT(sendToLogic(int,int,int)));                      //turns the clicked Signal into a Signal with Coord
            connect(this,SIGNAL(colorGreen(int,int,int)),button,SLOT(green(int,int,int)));                          //connects Widget and Button to color a button Green
            connect(this,SIGNAL(colorRed(int,int,int)),button,SLOT(red(int,int,int)));                              //connects Widget and Button to color a button Red
            connect(this,SIGNAL(colorBlack(int,int,int)),button,SLOT(black(int,int,int)));                          //connects Widget and Button to color a button Black


        }
    }

    /**
    / Generates Player 2 Field and sets color to Blue
    **/

    ui->gridLayout2->setVerticalSpacing(0);
    ui->gridLayout2->setHorizontalSpacing(0);
    for(int x = 0 ; x < 10 ; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0 ; y < 10; y++)
        {
            Button *button = new Button(x ,y,2);                                                               //New Objects
            ui->gridLayout2->addWidget(button,x,y);                                                          //adds buttons to left Widget
            button->setStyleSheet("background-color: blue");                                                 //sets all buttons to color blue
            connect(button,SIGNAL(mySignal(int,int,int)),this,SLOT(sendToLogic(int,int,int)));                       //turns the clicked Signal into a Signal with Coord
            connect(this,SIGNAL(colorGreen(int,int,int)),button,SLOT(green(int,int,int)));                           //connects Widget and Button to color a button Green
            connect(this,SIGNAL(colorRed(int,int,int)),button,SLOT(red(int,int,int)));                               //connects Widget and Button to color a button Red
            connect(this,SIGNAL(colorBlack(int,int,int)),button,SLOT(black(int,int,int)));                           //connects Widget and Button to color a button Black
            connect(this,SIGNAL(colorGreen(int,int,int)),button,SLOT(green(int,int,int)));                           //connects Widget and Button to color a button Green

        }
    }

}
void Widget::sendToLogic(int x,int y,int player)                               //sends GUI entries to Logic
{
    qDebug()<< "x" << x << "and y " << y << "and player" << player;
    emit GUItoLogic(x,y,player);
}

void Widget::errorMessage()                                         //recieves errorSignal and shows user "invalid Entry"
{
    ui->tbOut->append("invalid Entry.");
}

void Widget::closeWindow()                                          //closes widget window
{
    this->close();
}


void Widget::colorButtonGreen(int x,int y,int player)                          //sends Signal to Button to turn green
{
    emit colorGreen(x,y,player);
}

void Widget::colorButtonRed(int x,int y,int player)                            //sends Signal to Button to turn Red
{
    emit colorRed(x,y,player);
}

void Widget::colorButtonBlack(int x,int y,int player)                          //sends Signal to Button to turn Black
{
    emit colorBlack(x,y,player);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

The code manages to print out the right click whenever I click on a certain button. The problem I am having is when I add a coloring Signal all the buttons turn to that color instead of just the one button I clicked.

Button Class:

```
Button::Button(int _x, int _y,int _player): x(_x),y(_y),player(_player)
{
    connect(this,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(emitmySignal()));
}

void Button::emitmySignal()                                                                      // emit ein Signal mit Button Koordinaten, die gedruckt wurden
{
   // setStyleSheet("background-color: red");
   emit mySignal(x,y,player);
   clearFocus();
}
void Button::green(int x, int y,int player)
{
    qDebug()<< "x" << x << "and y " << y << player;
   this->setStyleSheet("background-color: green");
}
void Button::red(int x, int y,int player)
{
    qDebug()<< "x" << x << "and y " << y << player;
    setStyleSheet("background-color: red");
}
void Button::black(int x, int y,int player)
{
    qDebug()<< "x" << x << "and y " << y << player;
  //  setStyleSheet("background-color:black");
}
```

Comment: Please post the code of the methods, to let others understand and help you better. Please also clarify, in which method the above mentioned code is part of.

Comment: I added both the Widget class and the button class.

Answer (score 0):

Your `signal` is connected to all buttons. So every time it trigger it will call all button `slot`s.

Comment: So how should I approach this problem, I can't define the Signals elsewhere because the buttons exist only in this scope and Shouldn't the three integers be enough to make the signals unique from one another.

Comment: Your buttons seem to have x and y coordinates. Check them before painting. If their coordinates are the same as the signal do the painting else do nothing.